# Finding the Thevenin Equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

i found Rth to be 4kohms but i cannot seem to figure out Vth
i short circuited the voltages sources and open circuited the current source to get Rth.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this homework-style question doesn't actually ask a question of the poster's interest, and hence isn't a question that can be answered here.

Comment: i would like help to find Vth and Rth

Comment: Do you know how to do [source transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_transformation)?

Comment: i would like to think so but yet i am getting mulitple answers

Comment: @Princess so edit your question and add your attempts – we can't help you if we don't know where you make a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

It would be greatly beneficial to re-draw the circuit with the current sources orientated vertically, and obvious resistor connections between the top and bottom rails separated out. Perhaps you can use Thevenin on the current sources at this stage.

The overall \$\small R_{TH}\$ is not \$\small 4\:k\Omega \$ btw.